# How to convert a SINGLE char to system string C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm working on a program that displays the following chars/integers in a console app.
The code that I wrote works in console app, but doesn't work in form...
I also want to display these values in my form( textBox->text).

My myfunctions.h file:

```
    typedef struct{
    
        char Header         [23]; //the char I want to display is 23 characters long
        int  Version        [4];  //4 characters...
        char Projectname    [21];
        char Developer      [8];
        char email          [16];
        char Description    [132];
        char Unknown        [1]; 
    
    }PackedContent;
    
    void BinaryReader(){
    
    system("CLS");
    
    PackedContent t;
    
    fstream myFile;
    
    myFile.open("PackedContent.opf");
    
    if(!myFile){
    
    
        cout<<"An unknown error occured! Cannot read .opf file... exiting now... \n"<<endl;
        
    
    }else{
    
        cout    <<"Reading packed data content... done!\n"<<endl;
        
        myFile.read((char *)&t, sizeof(PackedContent));
    
    
        cout<<"\nHeader      :"         <<t.Header              <<endl; //  Header info [ok]
        
        //cout<<"\nVersion     :"           <<t.Version             <<endl; //  Project Version [err]
        
        cout<<"\nProject name:"         <<t.Projectname             <<endl; //  Project name
        
        cout<<"\nDeveloper name:"       <<t.Developer<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEmail       :"         <<t.email               <<endl; //  Developer email
        cout<<"\nDescription :"         <<t.Description         <<endl; //  Project description [ok]
        cout<<"Unknown"                 <<t.Unknown             <<endl;
    }
```

Form:

```
Binary Reader.H (form)
PackedContent t;

BinaryReader();
textBox1->Text = t.Header; // doesnt work...
```

I've aslo tried:
`textBox1->Text =  Convert::ToString(t.Header); //doesn't work...`

Comment: I think you need to tag for c++-cli and / or winforms

Comment: The thing about `char` arrays as strings, is that they need to be ***null-terminated***. Normally in plain standard C++ (which your form code most likely isn't, it's probably managed C++/CLI) then you could create a string from an arbitrary **un**-terminated array as `std::string(t.Header, 23)`. But considering the probably C++/CLI nature of your program you might need to find a C++/CLI specific way to do the same thing.

Comment: And your title as well as comment in the code is misleading, you don't have a "SINGLE char", you have an *array* of `char`. A "single char" would be a single `char`, not an array. You probably mean *"string"* in some places where you say "char"

Comment: You have forgot about terminating zero and this is why you have problems. If you what to store string in c-array which can have length of 23 you need `char[24]` to include tailing zero too. Anyway using this c-array to store text is C-style code not C++.

Comment: Also please provide [mcve] and describe actual result. "Doesn't work" is not a description of the problem.

Comment: @MarekR My problem is that, I cannot convert char Header [23]; to system string...

I only can convert char header if i remove [23]... [form]

In console application char Header [23]; cout<<"Header:"<<t.Header<<endl; works well. 

But it doesnt work in form application textbox->text: I cannot convert char [23] to system string. I can only use it as : System::String^ str = t.Header.ToString(); textBox1->Text = str;

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for commenting. How to make it null-terminated?
char Header [23]= 0; or NULL doesn't work in typedef struct...

I also tried memset(t.Header,0x00,23); also not working. working with console app, but doesnt work with forms...

Answer (score 3):

If your char array was null-terminated, like C-strings, you could have passed it as is to an std::string c'tor:

```
textBox1->Text = std::string(t.Header)
```

Your char array is not null terminated, so you should also provide the size, like this:

```
int headerSize = 1; // This variable is just for the example. Instead you can pass the size right in the function below

textBox1->Text = std::string(t.Header, headerSize)
```

Or:

```
textBox1->Text = std::string(t.Header, std::size(t.Header))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot about terminating zero and this is why you have problems.

If you what to store text in c-array which can have length of 23 you need `char[24]` (23 + 1) to include tailing zero too.

Anyway using this c-array to store text is C-style code not C++ and this should be avoided.

If you do not include terminating zero then for example this call `extBox1->Text = t.Header;` will try to finds it to perform conversion to `String`. This will lead to undefined behavior, result string will contain some trash at the end or it will end with a crash.

If your code records terminating zero in this structure, but reaches size limit, then you will have buffer overrun error.

Comment: There is an `std::string` c'tor that accepts a char array followed by a size. This should overcome the missing null-termination problem.

Comment: it is hard to tell without [mcve]. Note that when he stores data in this structure it can lead to buffer overrun error.